# How do I change the sharing settings for a series of Google Doc ids in a Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, looker-studio

I have a sheet where I'm pulling together a series of documents that have been submitted into a Google Form.  Since these documents are shared with the owner of the form, but not the person who submitted them, I want to automatically update the sharing settings for the documents so that they can be viewed by the person who submitted them.

Obviously, I could just update the sharing settings of the folder where the documents "live," but I want to ensure that the owner of the form and the person who submitted the document can open it, but not others.  This is important because I have Looker dashboard where people can search for their documents, but I don't want them to be able to open documents submitted by other people.

So, I need to update the sharing settings of the documents based on a spreadsheet that includes the document id for each document and the email I want to share with.

I created the spreadsheet in the image below and used =REGEXEXTRACT to find the document id after the = in the address of each document.  [Spreadsheet with three columns: File (Google Doc id),Email(the person to share with),URL(the original sharing URL of the document populated by the form)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmsHz.png)

I created a script that I thought would update the sharing for each document, but it is just re-sharing the doc id in the first row over and over.  I'm sure there's something very simple wrong with the code, but I'm new to this and I don't know what it is.  If someone could look at the below and let me know what I'm doing wrong, that would be amazing.

Here is the code:

```
function shareFile() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sharing Update');
  const fileId = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();
  const email = sheet.getRange(2,2, sheet.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
  const fileToShare = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

email.forEach(function(email) {
  if(email[1] != (null))
   fileToShare.addEditor(email[0]);
   }
)}
```

Thanks in advance for anyone willing to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, only the values of cells `sheet.getRange(2,1)` and `sheet.getRange(2,2, sheet.getLastRow()-1,2)` are used. I thought that this is the reason for your current issue of `but it is just re-sharing the doc id in the first row over and over.`.
- In order to achieve your goal, how about the following flow?

  1. Retrieve all values from the sheet.
  2. Add the editor permission with `addEditor` using the retrieved values.

When this flow is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function shareFile() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sharing Update');
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  values.forEach(([fileId, email]) => {
    if (fileId && email) {
      try {
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).addEditor(email);
      } catch ({ message }) {
        console.log({ fileId, message });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the file IDs and email addresses are retrieved from columns "A" and "B", and the editor permission is added to each file of file ID with each email address.

#### Reference:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

### Added:

About your following new question,

> My only challenge now is to make this only run on lines that haven't already been shared. I tried to create a script that would mark a third column (C) "Complete" when it was done and then would check if that was full before running the script, but I can't figure out how to make that work.

#### Sample script:

```js
function shareFile() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sharing Update');
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  const ranges = values.reduce((ar, [fileId, email, status], i) => {
    if (fileId && email && status != "Complete") {
      try {
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).addEditor(email);
        ar.push(`C${i + 2}`);
      } catch ({ message }) {
        console.log({ fileId, message });
      }
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (ranges.length == 0) return;
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("Complete");
}
```

- When this script is run, "Complete" is checked in column "C". When it is not existing, permission for the file is changed, and "Complete" is put into column "C".

Comment: Thank you so much!  This works perfectly.  I knew the script was pointing to a specific line before, but I was imagining some way to repeat that on each line (a la array in Google sheets).  I'm new to Apps Script and this is a great, elegant solution.

Comment: My only challenge now is to make this only run on lines that haven't already been shared.  I tried to create a script that would mark a third column (C) "Complete" when it was done and then would check if that was full before running the script, but I can't figure out how to make that work.

Comment: @Ryan Tanner-Read Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your 2nd new question, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you so much!  I appreciate.  Now that I see how this code works, I'm hoping that I can use it to do something similar in another project.  This is so helpful.